# can I rebase from develop branch into feature branch via team explorer?

Tags: git, visual-studio, team-explorer

I created my local branch X off of the develop branch a few days ago. Since that time, the develop branch has been updated with code branches from other developers. I want to get my local branch X up to date with the develop branch. I was thinking that I could use Rebase to do this via VS Team Explorer. However, Team Explorer appears to only have the option to Rebase *from* my current feature branch onto another branch.  Not the ability to Rebase from another branch (like develop) onto the current feature branch.  Is there a way to Rebase from another branch onto the current feature branch?  Or am I misunderstanding the Rebase implementation within VS Team Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rebase branch X onto the current state of the develop branch, then from the command line you would checkout branch X and run git rebase.  Team Explorer is set up to work the same way.  While you have branch X checked out, right click on develop (in the Branches page) and choose "Rebase onto".  This will rebase branch X onto develop.

A lower level explanation is this will calculate the merge base between branch X and develop to determine the commits that should be rebased.  It will then reset X to match develop and replay the commits.  Under the covers, Team Explorer in VS 2017 is actually running "git rebase".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rebasing applies changes from another branch to your local branch, I think the phrasing is just ambiguous.

Comment: based on the layout of team explorer, it looks like the intent is for the developer to execute the rebase command when the develop branch is the currently selected branch.  I can see the logic behind this because it helps remind the developer to pull the latest code for the develop branch before rebasing it into the feature branch. so "rebase from the current branch" (when the branch is develop) "onto branch" (selected feature branch) makes sense to me in this context.  does my understanding of this appear to be correct?

Comment: TheBatman - yes, ambiguous indeed! @user10816949 - it is the opposite I find (and matches Chad B's answer) and that's why "rebase onto" is so wrong for Visual Studio to state, IMO. At least for me, the word "rebase" means re-baseline something. So, I feel I want to re-baseline my feature branch. . .so I feel like I should rebase dev "onto" my feature branch, not rebase my feature branch onto dev. Yet, the latter is how you want to do things. So, one way is to make your feature branch current, then right-click and "rebase onto" then select "dev" from dropdown.